# How do i change NEI to cheat mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

**EXTRA PROBLEM**
I have NEI on minecraft with some other mods and NEI is supposed to have a saves thing on the left, and items on the right. The only thing on the left is the options. I want to see the saves and time changing options too.

***Cheat Mode***
When I click on a item to get it it keeps showing me the recipe.
Though in the options menu from NEI it is on cheatmode.
I saw another post saying I need to change something to this lockmode=-1 or cheatmode=2 but it is already that way. That didn't work how do i get it to give me the items and also recipe when I press R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That didn't work for me either. You have to change an option in the worlds save menu. Go to something like this C:\Users(Your Name)    \AppData\Roaming.minecraft\modpacks\Forge\saves\NEI\local(Your worlds name) and open NEI with notepad it should be a text document with a few lines change
{
    cheatmode=0 to cheatmode=2
}

You need to do this for every world it should also let you use recipes and usage with R&U and the options on the left should also work.